# How to use mod_rewrite with anchors but no [R=301]

Tags: mod-rewrite, anchor

I have a website build on jQuery scrollTo plugin. Each page is accessible via anchor's, ie. 
**www.domain.com/#page-one**
 and deeper 
**www.domain.com/#page-one--some-content**.

I'd like to create rule with mod_rewrite so address like

**www.domain.com/page-one** 
or 
**www.domain.com/page-one/some-content**

point to the above one. Its quite easy with [R=301] flag but I need my "clean" address **/page-one/some-content** to stay in address bar not changing to **#page-one--some-content**.

Why I need to change them? Because for some reasons I need to use alternative site for MSIE and Opera, kind of regular one with reloading every page. I need the same links for both sites which is obvious, I think.

I spent lots of time digging & reading about anchors in URL's and stuff, but I haven't reach my goal. If any one can help me, I'll appreciate!

Thanks, Kuba.

Comment: Can you provide your actual rules? And did you try just removing the [R]?

Comment: After deep research I found out it's impossible to rewrite address with # (keeping old address in address bar)

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php#$1 [NE]
```

This works excellent for me.