# How to avoid htaccess redirect-rewrite loop?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

My current htaccess does two simple url rewrites for two simple page. Here is the code.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^home/?$    index.php#home    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^contact/?$    index.php#contact    [NC,L]
```

now mywebsites.com and mywebsite.com/home are the same pages. I am using the twitter bootstrap carousel to flip slide between page without actually loading them.

Unfortunately the number of facebook share on mywebsite.com/home is 2000 and on mywebsite.com/ is 29. So I want to 301 redirect mywebsite.com/ to mywebsite.com/home but that puts the htaccess into an infinite loop.

any help will be widely appreciated.

Comment: Does the redirect from `mywebsite.com/home` to `mywebsite.com/index.php#home` have to be a hidden redirect? I'm not totally sure, but this seems to be not possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526203/how-to-use-mod-rewrite-with-anchors-but-no-r-301#comment6311714_5526203

Comment: Hi Christopher,
It is totally Possible and I am already doing it. In this case the pages are actually one page and they slide transition to each other on clicking the navigation menu. It is based on a jquery carousel.

Answer (score 1):

The following should allow for only ONE redirection.

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule .* - [L]
```

Does that help?